# why identity number in ef jump to a big number?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

i use entity framework 6.0 on my website .

i have a table to inserting some data and this table has identity column like ID (int) and my identity seed is equal to 1;

some time when i look at this table by sql management studio i encounter by jumping this ID to the big number ,for example from 30 jumped to 10024.

why this happens? is it a bug or what?

i past here my sample code that i insert a data to this table by some codes like this:

```
 using (var context = new MyModelDBEntities())
        {
             mytable mt=new mytable;
             mt.name=""; //for example
            context.mytables.add(mt);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

is this codes normal? what happend to my table then, that identity number jump to a big number?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not deleted all rows between 30 and 10024? SQL Server will not reuse ID it will just keep adding to last value.

Comment: yes I'm sure and it happens ore than one

Comment: In that case just like it was already mentioned in answers it could come from failed inserts. Can you add SQL for table definition? Does your column include `IDENTITY (1,1)` on it? or are you relying on your c# code to increment it?

Comment: yes, it does IDENTITY (1,1)

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8252

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be many reasons - one could be a failed attempt to insert 9,994 records (or multiple failed attempts that total 9,994 records).

An identity column does not guarantee *consecutive* IDs; it guarantees *unique* IDs.  If an insert attempt fails (or is part of a transaction that is rolled back) the ID that would have been generated is not re-used.

Another option is something inserting a specific ID after using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`.

In any case you've got over 2 billion IDs available so a gap of 10,000 or so shouldn't be cause for alarm.  If the gaps are getting *bigger* as time goes on then you may have a bigger problem as the gaps may be growing exponentially.

Comment: can you explain your answer on paragraph four

Comment: @motevallizadeh I've seen bugs where the "gap" is equal to the # of records currently in the table, so the "gaps" grow exponentially and you reach the 2 Billion limit sooner that of the gaps were consistent.  It's rare (and usually only happens with `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`) but something to watch out for.

Comment: @motevallizadeh Also that seems unlikely in this case as you jump from  30 to 10,000.  I would bet it's failed inserts.

Comment: +1 for identity insert AND failed inserts. Very true, if any code, scheduled job, or SQL script uses `SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable ON`, then they can insert any value they want and the the identity is re-seeded to the max value in that identity column after `SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable OFF` is called. Here is a SQL Fiddle that shows the failed insert and identity insert causing gaps. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2571f/1

Comment: @BateTech Thanks SQL Fiddle is a nice tools,I will use it.

Comment: This don't answer PO question. In my small project which do simple `CRUD` operations I'm pretty sure that I don't have 1000 failed inserts and I never used `SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable OFF`. It is more likely some internal issues with Microsoft productions. It is not possible to explain this anymore  => `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1002,1003,1004`

Answer (score 3):

Identity property on a column does not guarantee that it won't have gaps.  Here is from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx):

> **Consecutive values after server restart or other failures** –SQL Server
>   might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the
>   assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>   restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. ***If
>   gaps are not acceptable then the application should use a sequence
>   generator with the NOCACHE option or use their own mechanism to
>   generate key values.***
>
> **Reuse of values** – For a given identity property with specific
>   seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a
>   particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled
>   back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be
>   generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity
>   values are generated.